# Infinite page loading after running script with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to scrape a website. The first request with Selenium always works, but as soon as the second request is run, the page loads infinitely. All I can do is stopping the page manually, so the rest of requests continue working correctly. What can I do about it? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the full code you wrote? otherwise we cannot help

Comment: https://codeshare.io/EBQLd4